# Flutter folders in repository

Tags: android, ios, git, flutter, repository

I'm very new to Flutter and I've started a project using Android studio as IDE.

Why are there android/ios and .android/.ios folders? Should be upload all those folder to the repository or just android/ios?

Regards, Diego.

Comment: what is the relative path of .android/.ios folders you mentioned above ?

Comment: Just at the same level of android/ios

Comment: https://www.gitignore.io/api/android,androidstudio,flutter

Answer (score 0):

It's not that easy. There are some files, where you have to check for yourself, if you want to share them between the different developers.

There is an [interesting thread about this in the official Flutter repository](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12639).

Answer (score 0):

Since they are not on the [.gitignore](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/.gitignore) file, I think they should be gone to your repo too.
I don't have those files though, what are their relative path?

Comment: Just at the same level of android/ios